# I want to give color to the table-header (th) after I click on radio button

Tags: html, css, sass, html-table

this Is my code

https://codepen.io/mchedlo981/pen/ZErGPLN

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <th>
            <label for="1"><input id="1" type="radio">გამარჯობა</label>
        </th>
    <br>
        <th>
            <label for="2"><input id="2" type="radio">გამარჯობა</label> 
        </th>
    
    </tr>
    
</table>
    


th {
border: 1px solid;
width: fit-content;
```

}

table {
display: flex;
justify-content: center
}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have multiple ways to do this (you will need a little of Javascript).

I propose the next:

html file:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <th class="th">
            <label for="1"><input id="rad1"  name ="1" type="radio">red</label>
        </th>
    <br>
        <th class="th">
            <label for="2"><input id="rad2" name ="1"  type="radio">green</label>   
        </th>
    
    </tr>
    
</table>
```

css file:

```
th {
    border: 1px solid;
    width: fit-content;
    
}

table {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center
}
```

javascript file:

```
var th_list = document.getElementsByClassName("th");
document.getElementById("rad1").onclick = function() {
    for(var i = 0; i < th_list.length; i++) {
        th_list[i].style.setProperty("background", "red");
    }
};

document.getElementById("rad2").onclick = function() {
    for(var i = 0; i < th_list.length; i++) {
        th_list[i].style.setProperty("background", "green");
    }
};
```

Comment: It works but why does It coloring both th? and what if I have big table data, should I write all of their id or Is there any solution?

Comment: I thought that you want to change all the th elements.
So if you want to change only one th its easier, you only need to add an id on the th element, for instance: <th id="th1"> and on the js code 
var th1 = var th_list = document.getElementsById("th1");
document.getElementById("rad1").onclick = function() {
    for(var i = 0; i < th_list.length; i++) {
        th1[i].style.setProperty("background", "red");
    }
};

Comment: I will try It and let you know

Comment: medal https://codepen.io/mchedlo981/pen/ZErGPLN It is not working I think I made mistake.